# Simulating a delay in python unittest for boto3.client to test timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, boto3, python-unittest

I have a few lines of code here -

```
try:
    client = _get_client(region_name, connect_timeout, read_timeout, max_retries)
except Exception as e:
    log_exception("could not connect to param store boto3 client",param_name=param_name, err=e)
    return default_value
```

and my `_get_client` method is very simple -

```
def _get_client(region_name, connect_timeout, read_timeout, max_retries):
    config = Config(connect_timeout=connect_timeout,
                    read_timeout=read_timeout,
                    retries={'max_attempts': max_retries})
    return boto3.client("ssm", region_name=region_name, config=config)
```

What I want to do now, is test the `connect_timeout` and the `read_timeout` in a Python `unittest`. Does anyone know how to do such a thing? How do I simulate a latency to connect to a `boto3.client`?

Comment: Instead of simulating the latency, you can just mock it to raise it's timeout exception

Comment: thanks, is there an example you can point me to?